# Объединение массивов без повторений элементов

Tags: c++

Нужно объединить два массива в третий так, чтобы элементы, которые повторяются в обоих массивах, не добавлялись,
т.е. a={1,2,3} b={3,4,5} -> c={1,2,3,4,5}.

Делал много хитроумных конструкций - ни одна не работала нормально. Прошу помощи.

```
cout << "step1" << endl;
for (i = 0;i < MainCobj->n; i++) {
  MainCobj->c[i] = MainCobj->a[i];
}
cout << "step2" << endl;
itemp = MainCobj->n;
for (j = 0;j < MainCobj->m;j++) {
  for (k = 0;k, MainCobj->n;k++) { 
    if (MainCobj->b[i] == MainCobj->a[k]) { 
      continue; 
    } else { 
      MainCobj->c[itemp] = MainCobj->b[i]; 
    } 
    itemp++; 
  } 
}
```

Все элементы с `А` идут в `С`. Дальше 2 цикла, если есть совпадение - элемент не добавляется. `itemp` - это счётчик `С` массива.

Comment: Какие конкретно "конструкции" не работали - покажите. И расскажите своими словами алгоритмы их работы.

Comment: 'cout << "step1" << endl;
  for (i = 0;i<MainCobj->n;i++) {
   MainCobj->c[i] = MainCobj->a[i];
  }
  cout << "step2" << endl;
  itemp = MainCobj->n;
  for (j = 0;j < MainCobj->m;j++) {
   for (k = 0;k, MainCobj->n;k++) {
    if (MainCobj->b[i] == MainCobj->a[k]) { continue; }
    else {
     MainCobj->c[itemp] = MainCobj->b[i];
    }
    itemp++;
   }
  }
'

Все элементы с А идут в С. Дальше 2 цикла, если есть совпадение - элемент не добавляется. itemp - это счётчик С массива.

Comment: посмотри тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719337/merging-two-arrays-in-ascending-order-both-arrays-have-same-size и тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791266/c-concatenate-two-int-arrays-into-one-larger-array похожие темы и возможное решение

Comment: я бы вообще в `set` всё загнал и обратно... Ну или 2 указателя если элементы отсортированы.

Comment: пример у вас в вопросе целые числа использует, а заголовке упомянуты "строковые" массивы

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6):

Условие можно двояко интерпертировать. Если задача, чтобы все элементы были в итоге уникальными, то удобно использовать `std::set` или `std::unordered_set`:

```
#include <algorithm> // copy()
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <iterator>  // ostream_iterator<>
#include <set>

#define SIZE(array) (sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array))

int main()
{
  typedef int Value;
  Value a[] = {3,2,1,1,2,3}, b[] = {3,3,3,4,5,5};
  std::set<Value> c(a, a + SIZE(a));
  c.insert(b, b + SIZE(b));
  std::copy(c.begin(), c.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Value>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Сложность создания линейно-логарифмическая: `O(n*log n + m*log m)`, где `n`, `m` размеры `a` и `b`. Можно сделать время создания линейным,  используя `unordered_set`, если `Value` тип позволяет.

Пример:

```
$ g++ merge_all_unique.cc && ./a.out
1 2 3 4 5
```

Видно что результат отсортирован и нет повторяющихся элементов.

Если внутри `a` и `b` элементы могут повторяться, а нельзя только добавлять элементы из `b`, которые уже есть в `a`:

```
#include <algorithm> // copy()
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <iterator>  // ostream_iterator<>, begin(), end()
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  typedef int Value;
  Value a[] = {3,2,1,1,2,3}, b[] = {3,3,3,4,5,5};
  std::vector<Value> c(begin(a), end(a));
  std::unordered_set<Value> a_set(begin(c), end(c));
  std::copy_if(begin(b), end(b), std::back_inserter(c), [&a_set] (Value item) {
      return a_set.find(item) == a_set.end(); // item not in a
    });
  std::copy(begin(c), end(c), std::ostream_iterator<Value>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Сложность создания `c` линейная: `O(n + m)`.

Пример:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 merge_not_in_a.cc && ./a.out
3 2 1 1 2 3 4 5 5
```

Видно, что элементы не отсортированы и могут повторяться (сколько раз они в отдельных входных массивах присутствуют). `3` не копируется из `b`, потому что это число уже есть в `a`.

По вкусу, вместо алгоритмов, можно явные циклы использовать:

```
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <iterator>  // begin()
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  typedef int Value;
  Value a[] = {3,2,1,1,2,3}, b[] = {3,3,3,4,5,5};
  std::vector<Value> c(std::begin(a), std::end(a));
  std::unordered_set<Value> a_set(c.begin(), c.end());
  for (auto item : b) {
    if (a_set.find(item) == a_set.end()) { // if not in `a`
      c.push_back(item);                   //   copy from `b`
    }
  }
  for (auto item : c) {
    std::cout << item << ' ';
  }
}
```

Результат и время исполнения те же.

Answer (score 1):

Будет работать со многими контейнерами и даже с обычными массивами.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 10> arr1 = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    std::array<int, 5> arr2 = { 1,7,8,9,5 };

    std::copy_if(arr2.begin(), arr2.end(), arr1.begin() + 5, [&](const int& _1) {for (auto it : arr1) { if (it == _1)return false; }return true; });

    for (auto it : arr1) {

        printf_s("%d\n", it);
    }

    while (true)
    {
        Sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: не стоит использовать квадратичные алгоритмы, если линейный алгоритм также легко реализовать.

Comment: @jfs а можно подробнее, линейный это с `unordered_set`? или при условии что оба массива уже отсортиванны?

Comment: @pavel слово `set` на `unordered_set` замените в коде и всё в данном случае. Сортировки элементов это не требует, только чтобы Value тип можно было хэшировать (`std::hash<>`, `std::equal_to<>`).

Comment: @jfs да я понимаю. Просто у `unordered_set` есть нехорошая особенность, что иногда он медленнее обычного работает. На олимпиададх иногда очень боком вылазило.

Comment: @pavel представьте ввод имеет миллион элементов, тогда ваш код требует ~`10**12` операций по сравнению ~`10**6` для `unordered_set`.  Для кода в моём ответе задержки, которые вы упоминаете не применимы (только на чтение операции после создания), но в общем случае индивидуальная операция с `unordered_set` действительно может неожиданно долго выполняться (если букеты перестраивать необходимо), но в среднем это амортизируется. Ещё возможен вариант со зловредным вводом для некоторых реализаций (может быть актуально для веб-серверов), но даже это не  хуже квадратичного алгоритма.

Comment: @jfs безусловно) я хотел сказать что `O(n)` это оптимистично, я бы скорее `O(N log N)` реализовывал. Квадратичный алгоритм конечно же нет.

Comment: @pavel нет. Поведение линейно (амортизировано). Оптимизм тут ни причём. Почитайте как хэш-таблицы реализованы.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40696/discussion-between-pavel-and-jfs).